# Identify SMD IC marked J5

Tags: integrated-circuit, surface-mount, markings

I need help in identifying this smd Ic, which is a 6 pin smd package (most probably 1-3 watts led driver).

I have searched the smd marking sites:

1)https://www.s-manuals.com/smd/j5

2)https://smd.yooneed.one/code4a35.html

but the package is sot23-6 but i cant find similar one.

Ic image in first circuit ( marked J5CVC )

[image]

Ic image in second circuit ( marked J5EDE )

[image]

In some circuits its marked J5CTB also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly the Silergy Corp [SM8102A](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2001171834_Silergy-Corp-SM8102ABC_C479069.pdf) 18V DC-DC Step-Down Regulator.

It's in a SOT23-6 package with a pinout that seems to reasonably match the circuit you show (capacitor from BS to LX, resistor network on FB pin, GND to big plane). The marking is a 5 digit number with the first two being J5 and the latter three digits being a date code which would explain why it varies between boards.

[image: SM8102 Pinout and marking]

Comment: Thanks for the reference.